# Method Dependencies - Best Practices?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dependencies

What is the best way to deal with the properties that a method depends on to execute?

Let's say you have a class with 2 properties and a method that does something with those 2 properties. Would it be better to instantiate the class, set the properties, then execute the method (with no parameters); or instantiate the class, then execute the method, passing in parameters that will set the properties?

For example:

```
class Person ...
    string Name ...
    string Address ...
    void Save() {
        Database.SavePerson(this.Name, this.Address);
    }
```

--- or ---

```
class Person ...
        string Name ...
        string Address ...
        void Save(string name, string address) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Address = address;
            Database.SavePerson(this.Name, this.Address);
        }
```

In the first example, if Name and Address aren't already set before the Save method is called, you would get and error. So, it seems like you would have to validate that those properties were set in the method.

The second example forces the user to supply the data needed to execute the method. But, this seems a little redundant since the parameters being passed-in are already properties of the object.

Is there a "best" way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "best" way is whatever way makes more sense for your use cases.

Comment: Undoubtedly, your second example is a bad way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well firstly I would consider if having the entity responsble for its own persistence is the design you want.

If not, then a `Person` entity would expose the properties, and another type would be responsible for saving that `Person` entity (this would be the case if using something like the Repository pattern for example).

If the entity is responsible for persisting itself (as would be the case if you were using a rich domain model such as that used with a framework such as CSLA), then you would have just a parameterless `Save` method, and if the properties are required, then some form of validation framework would catch any missing requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would do neither.  The first example you have is similar to Active Record, while the second one makes no sense to me at all, if the function accepts arguments, then what is the point of having fields / properties?

The problem with both your methods is the `Person` class exposes the database logic, which you may not want.

What I would do is using the repository pattern:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonRepository()
{
    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        // do some database stuff
    }
}

// ...

Person person = new Person() { Name = "Jim", Address = "123 Fake Street" };

PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository();
personRepository.Add(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only let the method parameterless if the parameters can be deduced/resolved somehow, or if they never change.

Otherwise it becomes a dready [leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) where you need to understand how the method works in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an instance method that will automatically use its own properties without parameters or you have a static method that accepts any parameters passed to it

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        Database.SavePerson(Name, Address);
    }

    public static void Save(string name, string address)
    {
        Database.SavePerson(name, address);
    }
}
```

The general idea of an object is that each object is reponsible of its own data. However, a class can have a static method that can be used globally and is not bound to any object instance. Static methods cannot access instance members.

---

But the fundamental question is whether a save method should be included in the `Person` class at all. Instead I would change the parameter list of the `Database.SavePerson` method to

```
public static void SavePerson(Person person) { ... }
```

And use it like this

```
var p = new Person { Name = "John", Address = "Wall Street, NY" };
Database.SavePerson(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind - you are breaking [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by this method. Because you do **three** things - persisting entity, AND renaming person, AND changing its address. This is not clear from method's name. This is side effect.

So, to inform developers of what your method really does, you should rename it to `SaveAndRenameAndRelocate`. Not very good name? Agree.

Thus, I'd created parameterless method for saving entity in it's current state.

```
public void Save()
{
   // code, which should be somewhere in repository
}
```

If you need to rename person - do it via Name property. If you need to change address - do it via Address property. If it's not allowed to Save person without name and/or address - initialize these properties via constructor:

```
public Person(string name, string address)
{
   // null-check goes here
   Name = name;
   Address = address;
}
```

Btw that's not very good idea to make entity persist itself :)